# How to get the values from array with dicitionary in swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, nsarray

I want get the below json to my array for showing in `UITableview`

```
{
MyPets =     (
            {
        breed = "";
        breedvaccinationrecord = "";
        "city_registration" = "";
        "date_of_birth" = "";
        "emergency_contacts" = "";
        gender = m;
        "pet_id" = 475;
        "pet_name" = "IOS PET";
        petinfo = "http://name/pet_images/";
        "prop_name" = "";
        "qr_tag" = 90909090;
        species = Canine;
        "vaccination_records" = "";
        vaccinationrecord = "http://Name/vaccination_records/";
        "vet_info" = "";
    }
);
}
```

i am using below code to get values into array

```
if let dict = response.result.value {

            print(response)

                let petListArray = dict as! NSDictionary
            self.petListArray = petListArray["MyPets"] as! [NSMutableArray]}
```

in cellForRowAtIndexPath i am using this line to  display name in UILabel in TableCell

```
cell?.petName.text = self.petListArray[indexPath.row].valueForKey("pet_name") as? String
```

but it is crashing like

```
fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type
```

i am new to swift 2 please help me thanks in advance

Comment: Why are there random keys that don't have quotes around them?

Comment: that is responce from server and it is working fine in android so...i dont know much

Answer (score 0):

First of all declare `petListArray` as Swift `Array`, **do not** use `NSMutable...` collection types in Swift **at all**.

By the way the naming `...ListArray` is redundant, I recommend either `petList` or `petArray` or simply `pets`:

```
var pets = [[String:Any]]()
```

The root object is a dictionary and the value for key  `MyPets` is an array, so cast

```
if let result = response.result.value as? [String:Any],
   let myPets = result["MyPets"] as? [[String:Any]] {
      self.pets = myPets
}
```

In `cellForRow` write

```
let pet = self.pets[indexPath.row]
cell?.petName.text = pet["pet_name"] as? String
```

It's highly recomenended to use a custom class or struct as model. That avoids a lot of type casting.