# How to filter a NSArray by Key:value, that is in a NSDictionary

Tags: ios, swift

Im trying to figure out how to filter out the Dictionary of NSArrays by the value "name"

```
// Is an Array of a dictionary, by key : values

var teamFilteredList = [[String:Any]]()
var teamList = [[String:Any]]()
```

Fetch:

```
    let string = "https://api/connect/"
    let url = NSURL(string: string)
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let tache = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! NSArray {
            print(jsonObj)
            teamList = jsonObj as! [[String : Any]]

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.teamCollectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
    tache.resume()
```

This code is the result and gets put in teamList

JSON:

```
({
    id = 1;
    logo = "testLogo";
    name = "testTeam1";
    "url" = "https://example.com";
},
    {
    id = 2;
    logo = "testLogo";
    name = "testTeam2";
    "url" = "https://example.com";
},
    {
    id = 3;
    logo = "testLogo";
    name = "testTeam3";
    "url" = "https://example.com";
})
```

Example of what it looks like once put in teamList:

```
let example = [[id: "1", logo: "image", name: "testTeam1", url: "https"], [id: "2", logo: "image", name: "testTeam2", url: "https"]]
```

Code Trying to Filter:

```
 let array2Name = teamFilteredList.flatMap { $0["name"] }
    teamFilteredList = teamList.reduce(teamFilteredList, { result, value in
        !array2Name.contains(where: { $0 as! _OptionalNilComparisonType == value["testTeam3"] }) ? result + [value]: result
    })
```

So far this code has been horrible. But there's nothing else online that tells me how to do it cut dry. So I've been stuck.

leads to crash:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString'

**Update:**

I have a collection view that is populated from a fetch by a NSURL that gives me a Dictionary filled with NSArrays and i want to filter out all the NSArray indexes in that dictionary by a value that is already in the NSArray Indexes by the key: "name"

This answered Question in this link final answer, but its not up to date and yields errors.
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44269083/how-to-get-the-values-from-array-with-dicitionary-in-swift)

Comment: Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString . You are trying to store String to another data type. So its getting Crash

Comment: Ok, Thanks there's got to be a easier way to do this. @McDonal_11

Comment: what u r trying to do ?

Comment: I put it in the Update for you @McDonal_11

Comment: Can u show what JSON u r receiving ?

Comment: You are encouraged to use custom classes or structs instead of dictionaries. It makes things easy.

Comment: How the desired will output look like in json format?

Comment: I updated answer maybe will help, its simply a Dictionary with Arrays inside of it like. let example = [[id: "1", logo: "image", name: "testTeam1", url: "https"], [id: "2", logo: "image", name: "testTeam2", url: "https"]] @Mr.Bista

Comment: U displayed datas in CollectionView. then what to do ?

Comment: Am asking flow ?

Comment: With that JSON response, you want to create dictionary with array inside it with this format:  `[[id: "1", logo: "image", name: "testTeam1", url: "https"], [id: "2", logo: "image", name: "testTeam2", url: "https"]] `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's so, so much easier with a custom struct and `JSONDecoder`

Create a struct

```
struct Team : Decodable {
    let id : Int
    let logo : String
    let name : String
    let url : URL
}
```

Create the arrays

```
var teamList = [Team]()
var teamFilteredList = [Team]()
```

Decode the JSON

```
let string = "https://api/connect/"
let url = URL(string: string)!
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
    if let error = error { print(error); return }
    do {
        self.teamList = try JSONDecoder().decode([Team].self, from: data!)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.teamCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
task.resume()
```

And filter the array

```
teamFilteredList = teamList.filter{ $0.name == "testTeam3" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this predicate

```
teamFilteredList.filter({ fromDict in return !array2Name.contains(where: { $0 == fromDict["name"] as? String ?? ""})})
```

The trick is that Swift isn't expressive in its errors. It says that `don't use where`, why? because the compiler really expects a String, because your closure is not correct.

And if the `array2Name` is a dictionary also. Try to change the `where` clause to:

```
where: { ($0["name"] as? String ?? "<<Empty1>>") == (fromDict["name"] as? String ?? "<<Empty2>>") }
```

So the whole function would be:

```
teamFilteredList.filter({ fromDict in return !array2Name.contains(where: { ($0["name"] as? String ?? "<<Empty1>>") == (fromDict["name"] as? String ?? "<<Empty2>>") })})
```

If you want to learn more effective functional programming and you don't mind some JavaScript, try this

[Learn Effective Functional Programming in JavaScript)](http://reactivex.io/learnrx/)

Comment: closer than I've ever got so for, lol though i am getting an error 'Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type '[String : Any]' and 'String'

Comment: array2Name i replaced with the already populated variable teamList. and i got the error

Comment: It seems that `array2Name` is not an array of strings. This code is about array2Name is an array of strings.  So try this `where: { ($0["name"] as? String ?? "<<Empty1>>" == fromDict["name" as? String ?? "<<Empty2>>"]) }`

Comment: Did this <<Empty1>> and <<Empty2>>, to make the condition fail when both are not strings